# Check if input is integer in textbox in VB2010

Tags: vb.net, validation, integer

If user inputs something else than an integer, program will not proceed but will give a message box telling there is an error.

Here is what I have now and it's not working:

```
   Sub Validation0()
            If IsNumeric(curBat) Then
                ' Here, it still could be an integer or a floating point number
                If CLng(curBat) = curBat Then

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number greater than 0.", "Error",
 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
                End If
            End If

        End Sub
```

Comment: [Int32.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: `Dim result As Integer = 0  If Integer.TryParse(["TEXT"], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, result) Then (...)`

Comment: You need to start by handling the `Validating` event, which where validation should be done.  If the data fails validation then you can cancel the event and focus will not shift from the control.  Obviously you would display your message from that event handler.  You can do your validation and display your message from another method but you need to call that from the `Validating` event handler and it would have to return a `Boolean` to indicate success or failure so you can cancel the event on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to diversify your code

1) identify whether string is integer

2) then identify whether it is greater than 0

```
  Sub Validation0()
        If IsNumeric(curBat) Then
            ' Here, it still could be an integer or a floating point number          
            dim curBat2 as integer = Convert.ToInt32(curBat)
            If curBat2 >  0 Then

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number greater than 0.", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, 
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

If you want to round off integer value then use

```
     Math.Roundoff(curBat2)
```

Comment: If Convert.ToInt32 fails you will have an error; an expected error which means it should be avoided or handled.

Comment: You can use try method